# tidyverse's way to look up values in data frame given a series of keys

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

Suppose I have a data frame like the following

```
df=data.frame(x=1:5,y=c("a","b","c","d","e"))
```

where `y` is the key column. Sometimes I want to look up values of `x` corresponding to a series of keys in `y`. To accomplish this, I can

```
row.names(df)=df$y
df[c("b","d","c"),c("x")]
```

and I will get

```
[1] 2 4 3
```

Note the order of values returned is the same as that of the series of given keys.

Now I want to achieve the same thing using tidyverse's tibble. But since tibble does not have `row.names`, I have no idea how to do it.

My question is, what is the "most clever" way (or idiomatic way, to borrow a term from Python) to look up values in a tibble given a series of keys, following the order of the keys?

Answer (score 1):

The non-rownames way of doing this with a data.frame is

```
df[match(c('b', 'd', 'c'), df$y), 'x']
```

This works with tibbles as well. Alternatively, use `dplyr` verbs:

```
df %>% slice(match(c('b', 'd', 'c'), y)) %>% pull(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use filter

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  x = 1:5,
  y = c("a","b","c","d","e")
)

df %>% 
  filter(y %in% c("b","d","c"))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x y    
#>   <int> <chr>
#> 1     2 b    
#> 2     3 c    
#> 3     4 d
```

Created on 2018-07-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).